# How can I create different object types without using switch case?

Tags: java, oop

I've done my first OOP project in Java. It is a project for my university course, it consists in a Logic Circuit Simulator with GUI. It works, but the problem is that the creation of a new different components is done using a switch case and my professor doesn't want me to use it. The code below runs when someone press the "Create" button on the GUI. The type "ComponenteLogico" is a superclass, and the classes "portaAND", "portaOR", "portaNAND" and company are all "ComponenteLogico" subclasses. How could I avoid the switch case?
Sorry if I used a bad english

```
 int inputs=jComboBox1.getSelectedIndex()+2;
        ComponenteLogico comp=null;
        if(jList1.getSelectedValue() == null)
        {
            System.out.println("Nessun componente creato");
            System.out.println("prova1");
        }//nel caso dell'aggiunta di una nuova classe bisogna aggiungere la voce corrispondente nello switch case sottostante
        else switch (jList1.getSelectedValue()) {
            case "AND":
                {
                    comp= new portaAND(inputs);
                    break;
                }
            case "OR":
                {
                    comp = new portaOR(inputs);
                    break;
                }
            case "NAND":
                {
                    comp = new portaNAND(inputs);
                    break;
                }
            case "NOR":
                {
                    comp = new portaNOR(inputs);
                    break;
                }
```

Comment: `if` and `else if` can always replace any switch statement. But also get a better professor, because what you wrote is the right way to do this.

Comment: *get a better professor* - or understand what the prof is really asking.

Comment: He said me to try to find a better solution because this doesn't respect the Open-Closed principle

Comment: Does he want you to use factories to do this. If this is about open-closed then he may be asking you to use the factory pattern.

Comment: Even if you move to a pattern, it does not mean that the switch is no good, just where the switch is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something along the lines of the command pattern/factory pattern: have a `Map<String, Function<Integer, ComponentLogico>>`, populate it somewhere upon program start up (i.e in a constructor):

```java
class A {
    private final Map<String, Function<Integer, ComponentLogico>> componentMap;

    public A() {
        componentMap = new HashMap<>();
        // Lambda syntax
        componentMap.put("AND", (inputs) -> new portaAND(inputs));
        componentMap.put("OR", (inputs) -> new portaOR(inputs));
        componentMap.put("NAND", (inputs) -> new portaNAND(inputs));
        componentMap.put("NOR", (inputs) -> new portaNOR(inputs));

        // Or use even more condensed syntax with method references:
        componentMap.put("AND", portaAND::new);
        componentMap.put("OR", portaOR::new);
        componentMap.put("NAND", portaNAND::new);
        componentMap.put("NOR", portaNOR::new);
    }

    public void something() {

        ...

        String componentName = jList1.getSelectedValue();
        if (!componentMap.contains(componentName)) {
            // Invalid name (not in map)
        }

        ComponenteLogico comp = componentMap.get(jList1.getSelectedValue()).apply(inputs);

        ...

 
    }


}
```

Notice, we effectively store the constructor to each type of `ComponenteLogico` in a `Map`, where we can get that constructor by using its name. We can then call this constructor as a `Function<int, ComponenteLogico>`, which has a method `ComponenteLogico apply(int value)`.

- More information on Function interface: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html
- More information on Method References: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html
- More information on Lambda expressions: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html